# Python Pandas - read_csv makes duplicates to NaN

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am currently working with pandas on a Dataframe and after reading a csv file and converting a specific column into str, pandas seems to transform all duplicates of this row into NaNs.

```
bla = pd.read_csv(bla_path, sep=',',converters={'order_id':str})
```

and it gives me this results:

```
 internal_conversion_id        order_id  conversion_target_id  \
0                    85            9222                 67   
1                    20            9224                 65   
2                    20             NaN                 65   
3                    20             NaN                 65   
4                    33            9233                 67   
5                    33             NaN                 67
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing? The original file does contain the duplicates.

EDIT: I just checked - this also happens, when i don't use `converters`.

EDIT 2: here some lines from the original csv:

```
internal_conversion_id,order_id,conversion_target_id,product_nr
85,9222,67,1
20,9224,65,1
20,9224,65,2
20,9224,65,3
33,9223,67,1
33,9223,67,2
```

EDIT3:

ok, i think i found the source.

At some point in the code I wanted to create a second variable with the same content as the first one, but without the duplicates. Pandas deletes all the duplicates in the first variable too. How can i stop Pandas from doing so?

here is the piece of code:

```
bla2 = bla

bla2['order_id'] = bla2['order_id'].drop_duplicates()
bla2 = bla2[pd.notnull(bla2['order_id'])]
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the original csv file?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates?

Comment: Without having a look at your CSV file, its hard to help. Post the head of your csv file like @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso said

Comment: If that's your input file, why are you using `sep=','`?

Comment: @ Alberto - the lines i posted are separated by Excel.

Comment: If you don't post the csv file (as opposed to whatever it is you are doing with it in Excel), it's impossible to diagnose what the problem is.

Comment: i edited the lines - they look like a regular csv. It's just really strange that the first and third column don't have this problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanted to just drop the duplicates you could've done it this way:

```
bla2 = bla2.drop_duplicates(subset='order_id')
```

what you did was to overwrite the column with the returned results from `drop_duplicates` for that column by doing this:

```
bla2['order_id'] = bla2['order_id'].drop_duplicates()
```

at that point you introduced `NaN` where the values were duplicates:

```
In [3]:
df['order_id'].drop_duplicates()

Out[3]:
0    9222
1    9224
4    9223
Name: order_id, dtype: int64

In [4]:
df['order_id'] = df['order_id'].drop_duplicates()
df

Out[4]:
   internal_conversion_id  order_id  conversion_target_id  product_nr
0                      85      9222                    67           1
1                      20      9224                    65           1
2                      20       NaN                    65           2
3                      20       NaN                    65           3
4                      33      9223                    67           1
5                      33       NaN                    67           2
```

However, your last line of code should've worked:

```
In [5]:
df = df[pd.notnull(df['order_id'])]
df

Out[5]:
   internal_conversion_id  order_id  conversion_target_id  product_nr
0                      85      9222                    67           1
1                      20      9224                    65           1
4                      33      9223                    67           1
```

So I don't know if you're getting confused

**EDIT**

if you want to make a copy then just make a copy:

```
bla2 = bla.copy()
```

then you can do whatever you want with `bla2` and it won't affect `bla`

or you create `bla2` from the result of `bla.drop_duplicates`:

```
bla2 = bla.drop_duplicates(subset='order_id')
```

Comment: Yes, because `drop_duplicates()` makes a deep copy of the frame.  The broken code in the OP had nothing to do with CSV loading, and was simply because OP misunderstood reference semantics of Python.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I know, I wish people would try to run the code they post along with their data and include everything relevant, it's incredible to me how this isn't registering with people when they try to explain what's going wrong

Comment: hi, thanks for the input. unfortunately i cannot post the whole code. however removing the second line doesn't change the output of the first variable. I guess `bla2 = bla` is not the right way to create a second variable with the same content in pandas,right?

Comment: Sorry are you telling me that `bla2 = bla2.drop_duplicates(subset='order_id')` doesn't work?

Comment: I think I understand your problem, you want to make a `copy` if you don't want to modify the original or you just do `bla2 = bla.drop_duplicates(subset='order_id')`

Comment: sorry, my mistake - your approach seems to fix it. thank you very much. was stuck on that quite a while.

Comment: for future reference when posting a problem include raw data, code and desired output, the code must be runnable and reproduce the problem, it wastes a lot of people's time including yours if you fail to do this. You should consider what would you think if you saw your own question before all the edits and failed to reproduce the problem